# How to lower pandoc verbosity using env. var (when it is invoked via nbconvert)?

Tags: logging, jupyter-notebook, pandoc, nbconvert, verbosity

The `--atx-headers` command is deprecated (in favor of `--markdown-headings=atx`), as pandoc noisily reminds us, displaying this warning almost 40 times in a row:

```
[WARNING] Deprecated: --atx-headers. Use --markdown-headings=atx instead.
[WARNING] Deprecated: --atx-headers. Use --markdown-headings=atx instead.
[..]
[WARNING] Deprecated: --atx-headers. Use --markdown-headings=atx instead.
[WARNING] Deprecated: --atx-headers. Use --markdown-headings=atx instead.
```

Unfortunately the old option is still used by `jupyter nbconvert --to asciidoc` for invoking `pandoc`.

So how to change `pandoc` output verbosity to "ERROR" (that will suppress this and other warnings) while invoking `nbconvert`, e.g. by using env. variables (the only method that comes to mind in this situation)? The [docs](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/5.1-general-options-1.html) indicate that `pandoc` seems to lack such an option.